# expo why is my app faster if I enable remote debug?

Tags: react-native, expo

in expo I enable Remote Debugging. I was excited because my app was faster xd. But Why is it faster if I run remote debug ? If I disable debugging my app is a little bit slower.

Can anyone explain me why is it like this ?

Answer (score 0):

From the expo page on [Debugging](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/debugging/#remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer-tools)

> Rather than running your app's JavaScript on your phone, it will instead run it inside of a webworker in Chrome.

My guess is that your phone isn't as powerful as your computer so it's slower to run the javascript